# Copy multiple rows from a spreadsheet to another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script that copy a selected row from a spreadsheet to another spreadsheet, from the column A to the column D.
It works fine.
The problems are 3:

1. How to change the columns from A to D with the columns C and E.
2. The script works only with one row selected, how can I copy multiple rows selected at the same time.
3. When the script is terminated, I would that in column H appears the value `Sent` for the rows copied.

Thanks in advance.

```
function main() {

transfer("....", "Foglio1", "Foglio1");

}
function transfer(targetId, sourceSheetName, targetSheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  var last = sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var data = sourceSheet.getRange(last, 1, 1, 4).getValues();

  // copy data
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetId);
  var targetSheet = ss2.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  //get last row
  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  //write data
  targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length)
           .setValues(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

1. **How to change the columns from A to D with the columns C and E?**

Please have a look at the arguments of [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns):

**Replace**

`var data = sourceSheet.getRange(last, 1, 1, 4).getValues();`

**with**

`var data = sourceSheet.getRange(last, 3, 1, 3).getValues();`

---

2. **The script works only with one row selected, how can I copy multiple rows selected at the same time?**

You can use [getHeight](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getheight) to find the number of rows selected and pass it to `getRange`:

```
var height = sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getHeight();  
var data = sourceSheet.getRange(last, 3, height, 3).getValues();
```

---

3. **When the script is terminated, in column H appears the value "Sent" for the rows copied.**

You can just set the values of column H to `Sent` for the selected rows:

`sourceSheet.getRange(last, 8, height).setValue('Sent');`

---

### Solution:

```
function main() {

transfer("....", "Foglio1", "Foglio1");

}

function transfer(targetId, sourceSheetName, targetSheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  var last = sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var height = sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getHeight();  
  var data = sourceSheet.getRange(last, 3, height, 3).getValues();

  // copy data
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetId);
  var targetSheet = ss2.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  //get last row
  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  //write data
  targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3, data.length, data[0].length)
           .setValues(data);
  
  sourceSheet.getRange(last, 8, height).setValue('Sent');
}
```

Comment: Thanks @marios for your reply. It works perfectly, but the problem is when the rows selected are not contiguous. How can i solve in the code?

Comment: Unfortunately, that can not be solved like that. You might need to apply a different logic which I need to research. Could you please post a different question so other experts (including me can also help) ? Stackoverflow does not allow for follow up questions :) Sorry for the incovenience and consider accepting the answer if it addressed your original issues :) @Popoff

Comment: Ok, thanks @marios The new question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64367425/copy-contiguous-rows-from-a-spreadsheet-to-another-spreadsheet