# Copy not contiguous selected rows from a spreadsheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

With this script is possible to copy the selected rows from a spreadsheet to another, from the column C to column E. 
When the script is terminated, in the "source" spreadsheet, in column H appears the value `sent` for the rows copied.
The problem is that the script take the rows selected in a contiguous range and so not with the possibility to copy not contiguous selected rows.
How can I solve this?

```
function main() {

transfer("....", "Foglio1", "Foglio1");

}

function transfer(targetId, sourceSheetName, targetSheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  var last = sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  var height = sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getHeight();  
  var data = sourceSheet.getRange(last, 3, height, 3).getValues();

  // copy data
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetId);
  var targetSheet = ss2.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  //get last row
  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  //write data
  targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3, data.length, data[0].length)
           .setValues(data);
  
  sourceSheet.getRange(last, 8, height).setValue('Sent');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to copy the columns "C" to "E" of the selected rows in the source sheet to the destination sheet using Google Apps Script.
- When the values are copied, you want to put the value of "Sent" to the column "H" in the source sheet.
- In your case, the selected rows are not only the continuous rows, but also the discrete rows.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, in order to retrieve the selected ranges, I would like to propose to use `getActiveRangeList()` and the method of spreadsheets.values.batchGet in Sheets API.

  - I think that Spreadsheet service can also achieve your goal. But I thought that when Sheets API is used, the process cost will be low. So in this answer, I would like to propose the method using Sheets API.
- In order to put the value of "Sent", I used the range list.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

In this case, `transfer()` is modified. Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services).

```
function transfer(targetId, sourceSheetName, targetSheetName) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sourceSheetName);
  
  // --- I modified below script.
  var ranges = sourceSheet.getActiveRangeList().getRanges().reduce((o, r) => {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numRows = r.getNumRows();
    o.getValues.push(`${sourceSheetName}!C${row}:E${row + numRows - 1}`);
    o.setValue.push(`${sourceSheetName}!H${row}:H${row + numRows - 1}`);
    return o;
  }, {getValues: [], setValue: []});
  var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(ss.getId(), {ranges: ranges.getValues}).valueRanges.reduce((ar, v) => ar.concat(v.values), []);
  
  data = data.map(r => !r ? Array(3).fill("") : (r.length < 3 ? r.concat(Array(3 - r.length).fill("")) : r));  // Added by OP's 3rd question in the comment.
  // ---
  
  // copy data
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(targetId);
  var targetSheet = ss2.getSheetByName(targetSheetName);
  //get last row
  var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
  //write data
  targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);  // Modified by OP's 2nd question in the comment.
  sourceSheet.getRangeList(ranges.setValue).setValue('Sent');  // Modified
}
```

- In this case, both the continuous rows and the discrete rows can be used.
- When the discrete rows are selected, in this sample, the order of select is the order of the values. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [getActiveRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getactiverangelist)
- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)

Comment: Only a clarification @Tanaike, in the destination sheet, the script write the data starting from column C. How to start from column A?

Comment: @Popoff Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your additional question, when you want to put the retrieved values from the column "A", please modify `targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 3, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);` to `targetSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);`.

Comment: there is an issue if a row has only 3 of 7 column with the values inside (for example A,B,C,) and the second row there are the values for all the columns, the script return an error and copies only the first row(the row with only 3 values inside)

Comment: @Popoff Thank you for replying. About your new issue, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Tanike Now, the issue is solved. Naturally if I would change the columns for the copy (for example copy only A, C, E, columns) I have to change this row? o.getValues.push(`${sourceSheetName}!C${row}:E${row + numRows - 1}`);

Comment: @Popoff Thank you for replying. I'm glad your 3rd question. About your 4th question, in this case, I think that it is a bit complicated and it is required to modify the process of script. Because in the current script, it supposes that the continuous columns are used from your question. So I would like to propose to post your 4th question as new question. I deeply apologize my first proposal method cannot be used for your all situations. This is due to my poor skill. I would like to study more and more.

Answer (score 2):

**In addition to the elegant solution proposed by Tanaike, I would like to add for completion's sake a simple solution:**

- You are defining `var height = sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getHeight();`
- The method [getHeight()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getheight) returns the height of an (adjacent) range.
- If instead you want to copy all the range until the last data containing row - including empty rows, you can define instead:

  `var height = sourceSheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow() - last + 1;`
- Now you will select and copy al the rows between the actively selected one and the last data containing row - including empty rows inbetween.
- Mind that for large amounts of data, Tanaike's solution will be more efficient.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Also I think that your answer is useful for a lot of users.

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike. You answer is much more elegant, I just had the thought to provide additionally something simpler, which might be interesting for some users as you say.

Comment: When I think the process cost of the situation, there are the cases that the script becomes a bit complicate. So in this case, I think that by your answer, the solution for achieving OP's goal became more important for a lot of users. Thank you, too.

Comment: @ziganotschka your solution works avoiding the problem I have mentioned on top: "there is an issue if a row has only 3 of 7 column with the values inside (for example A,B,C,) and the second row there are the values for all the columns, the script return an error and copies only the first row(the row with only 3 values inside)", but not works for not contiguous rows.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your issue correctly, can you provide a sample sheet that reproduces this issue and also provide the exact error message?